# How to deploy Laravel 4 Apps on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

I know that Heroku supports many different environments in the Cedar stack including [PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-deploy-php-to-heroku-in-seconds/).
The tipical folder structure of a Laravel 4 app is the following:

```
app/
bootstrap/
public/
    packages/
    index.php
vendor/
composer.json
phpunit.xml
```

Note 2 things:

1. The main **index.php** file is not located in the root, is under the public folder.
2. There is a **composer.json** file and Heroku needs to install all the project dependencies automatically just like gems in Ruby apps.

So my question is:
Is there a way to deploy this kind of apps on Heroku ??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd love to know this too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Even i'd love to know this, Please post here if anyone got answer.

Comment: [This buildpack](https://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php) by @Wing Lian seems to work well. You'll need to change your `composer.json` [according to this tutorial](http://blog.enge.me/post/a-comprehensive-tutorial-for-deploying-laravel-4-on-heroku) to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a custom buildpack to set the document root and executes a script that integrates composer too. In [Heroku's Buidlpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) you would need to update the bin/compile script to handle composer and conf/httpd.conf to set the document root. Also, Heroku's buildpack does not have mcrypt compiled in, so Laravel 4 won't work with that buildpack. I've included many updates that include mcrypt, composer, and custom document roots in [my branch of the buildpack](https://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php).

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has recently released a official PHP buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php. It's new and i had some initial troubles with it. but it should improve. It supports PHP or HHVM.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to specify your application's entry point in an Procfile, place it in  in the root directory of your application. In your case the contents would be:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#define-a-procfile